# EWS Managed API when using ExtendedPropertyDefinition displays property in header in lower case?

Tags: web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, ews-managed-api

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
 service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("hghgh", "hghg","yuu");
 service.AutodiscoverUrl("rtrtrtrtrtrrrgrgfgfgg@a.com");

EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
   message.Subject = "Subject";
   message.Body = "Body text comes here";
   message.ToRecipients.Add("jack@yahoo.com");

ExtendedPropertyDefinition cUID = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.InternetHeaders, "CITUID", MapiPropertyType.String);

message.SetExtendedProperty(cUID, "ID-12345678");
   message.SendAndSaveCopy();

Result seen in the header of the message in MS Outlook:

.........

cituid:ID-12345678 ----> this is property appearing as header in MS Outlook headers

As you know above I have created an extended property above that will appear as a header

Question : Is there a way by which the header can be set to display in UPPER CASE. As there is another 3rd party product that cannot parse the header as it appears in lower case.

Is there a way I can use a 'X-somthing' to appear as a header. I have heard that Exchange Server does not like 'X-..' being used as custom headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the default behaviour of MS Exchange Server 2007 to propogate custom headers in lower case. Headers will not display in Mixed/Upper case, they will ONLY display in LOWER CASE.

The custom headers can be propogated by MS Exchange Server 2007 to both Mapi and Non-Mapi clients.